# A hierarchical clustering in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

I'm currently working on a project in bioinformatics where drugs will be analyzed and results should be grouped according to similarity patterns.

For this, I use algorithms such as Euclidean distance and Mahalanobis distance. I'm currently using the library [Clusterfck](http://harthur.github.com/clusterfck/) but that is very limited and generates information completely out of default.

I wonder if there are other libraries in JavaScript or PHP that have implemented these calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with real data, I would not recommend using either Javascript or PHP. Both are interpreted and slow, and are better suited to rendering and displaying web content. For the same reason, you'll probably not find too many libraries for this in Javascript other than clusterfck. Better to do your analysis in some other language and use those to render it.

But, I'll share some libraries in other languages:

- [clustering in scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html)
- [scipy-cluster](http://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/), an extension to scipy that does similar stuff
- [hac](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/hac), a Java implementation
- [fastcluster](http://math.stanford.edu/~muellner/fastcluster.html), for R and Python